# Error: java: cannot find symbol symbol: class MockitoJUnitRunner

Tags: java, maven, junit, mockito, dropwizard

I am starting a fresh Dropwizard project and I am not able to use `MockitoJUnitRunner` to run tests.

I am able to run the main application. So, I am guessing that it is not a JRE/JDK problem.

Here are a few files from my project:

`pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

`FooTest.java` (For the sake of simplicity, I removed logic.)

```
import org.junit.Test;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class FooTest {
  @Test
  public void testSout() {
    System.out.println("This tests works.");
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error.

> Error:(20, 10) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol: class MockitoJUnitRunner

Comment: Did you add Mockito dependency in pom?

Comment: Like @samabcde said, you most likely did not include this in your dependencies. Check this https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all

Comment: You will need a dependency on Mockito as well to import the class `MockitoJUnitRunner` from the proper package`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First add the dependency to [Mockito](https://mockito.org) to you project, second import the class from the proper location.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.4</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

In your class do the proper import.

```
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
```

**NOTE:**
Your code doesn't really use any of the Mockito annotations like `@Mock` or `@Spy` so not sure why you even want to run it with the special mockito runner. Currently it will only slow down your test runs.